# Echo multiple variables in same line Bash

Tags: bash, echo

I want to echo two variables on the same line.
I want to store 2015-03-04.01.Abhi_Ram.txt in a variable FILENAME and 10 in a variable COUNT and echo them simultaneously.

Sample.txt

> 2015-03-04.01.Abhi_Ram.txt  10
>   2015-03-04.02.Abhi_Ram.txt  70

Below is the code I came up with:

```
for line in `hadoop fs -cat sample.txt`
do

VAR="${line}"
FILENAME=`echo ${VAR}|awk '{print $1}'`
COUNT=`echo ${VAR}|awk '{print $2}'`
COUNT_DT=`date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`
echo db"|"Abhi_Ram"|"record_count"|"${FILENAME}"||"${COUNT}"||"${COUNT_DT} >> output.txt
done

I want the output as:
```

> db|Abhi_Ram|record_count|2015-03-04.01.Abhi_Ram.txt||10||timestamp
>   db|Abhi_Ram|record_count|2015-03-04.02.Abhi_Ram.txt||70||timestamp

```
I'm getting the output as:
```

> db|Abhi_Ram|record_count|2015-03-04.01.Abhi_Ram.txt||||timestamp
>   db|Abhi_Ram|record_count|10||||timestamp
>   db|Abhi_Ram|record_count|2015-03-04.02.Abhi_Ram.txt||||timestamp
>   db|Abhi_Ram|record_count|70||||timestamp

Could someone point me what I am missing?

Comment: Why are you calculating the date inside the loop, when it doesn't make use of any variable being set? That's making your loop much slower / more expensive than it would otherwise need to be, if you put the `date` call outside, to happen only once before the loop starts.

Comment: Also, if you're using a new enough bash (4.1 or 4.2), there's a `printf` builtin for date formatting, making use of the external `date` command unnecessary.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Consider:

```
while read filename count
do
    count_dt=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    echo "db|Abhi_Ram|record_count|${filename}||${count}||${count_dt}"
done <sample.txt >>output.txt
```

This produces the file:

```
$ cat output.txt 
db|Abhi_Ram|record_count|2015-03-04.01.Abhi_Ram.json||10||2015-08-10 14:42:39
db|Abhi_Ram|record_count|2015-03-04.02.Abhi_Ram.json||70||2015-08-10 14:42:39
```

Notes:

1. It is best practice to use lower or mixed case for your shell variables.  The system uses upper case variables and you don't want to accidentally overwrite one.
2. The many double-quotes in the `echo` statement were unnecessary.  The whole of the output string can be inside one double-quoted string.
3. If you want to read a file one line at a time, it is safer to use the `while read ... done <inputfile` construct.  The `read` statement also allows us to easily define the `filename` and `count` variables.
4. For command substitution, many prefer the form `$(...)` over the backtick form.  This is because (a) the `$(...)` makes the beginning and end of the command substitution visually distinct, (b) the `$(...)` form nests well, and (c) not all fonts clearly show backticks as different from regular ticks.  (Thanks Chepner.)
5. For efficiency, the redirection to `output.txt` has been moved to the end of the loop.  In this way, the file is only opened and closed once. (Thanks Charles Duffy.)
6. Unless you need `count_dt` updated with each individual entry, it could be placed before the loop and set just once everytime `sample.txt` was processed.  If you have an up-to-date version of bash (no Mac OSX), then the `count_dt` assignment can be replaced (Thanks Charles Duffy) with a native bash statement (no shelling out required):

   ```
   printf -v count_dt '%(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)T'
   ```

Comment: I'd suggest making it `read -r`, to avoid dropping any backslash literals. (Granted, they're not _likely_ in filenames, but they are _possible_).

Comment: I'd also suggest putting a `>output.txt` on the **outside** of the loop, so you only open `output.txt` once, rather than re-opening the file every time you run `echo`, as done with the `>>output.txt` on the echo command.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good idea.  Answer updated to move the redirection outside the loop.

Comment: (Would also greatly improve efficiency to calculate `count_dt` outside the loop... or use the shiny new recent-4.x feature `printf -v count_dt '%(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)T' -1` to do the calculation in native bash rather than shelling out to an external `date` command for every row processed).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Nice!  That `printf` is new to me.

Comment: @John1024 : Thank you for the comments. I have made the modifications as per your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

John1024 has explained how to do this correctly; I'd like to take a look at why the original version didn't work. The basic problem is that `for` loops over *words*, not over lines. The file has two words on each line (a filename and a count), so it runs the loop twice per line. To see this, try:

```
for line in `hadoop fs -cat sample.txt`
do
    echo "$line"
done
```

...and it'll print something like:

```
2015-03-04.01.Abhi_Ram.txt
10
2015-03-04.02.Abhi_Ram.txt
70
```

...which isn't what you want at all. It also has some other unpleasant quirks, like if the input file contained the word "*", it'd insert a list of filenames in the current directory.

The `while read ... done <file` approach is the right way to iterate over lines in a shell script. It just happens to also be able to split each line into fields without having to mess with `awk` (in this case, `read filename count` does it).